# SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT with JQuery GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ssl

There is a server which provides a XML under a certain URL (for example: `https://myxmlfile`). For this server request is a p12 certificate with password needed which I installed in Firefox and on my machine. If I enter the URL in the webbrowser (`https://myxmlfile`), the xml will be shown.

Now I try to make a jQuery GET Request from my website (which is just running on my local machine at the moment). In that GET Request I want to get the same XML, but this doesn't work and I get `SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT`.

I'm pretty new to certificates. So is it not enough to install the certificate in the browser? Do I have to send the certificate in the GET request or something like that?

This is the request:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: 'https://myxmlfile',
 data: 'subscriptionID=0011',
 dataType: "xml" ,
 async: false,
 error: function(xhr, status, error){
   console.log('Error: '+ xhr.status+ ' - '+ error);
   console.log("error");
 },
 success: function(xml) {
   console.log(xml);
 }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this a self-signed certificate? If so, that's your issue. The URL only works when called directly because you manually accepted the certificate.

Comment: I'm not sure. I got the certificate and the password from the organisation who provides the server. I just had to enter the password once at the installation. If I enter the url in the webbrowser there is no retype for the password needed

Comment: Did you pay for the certificate? If so it's unlikely to be self-signed. Also, you state that the site is running on your local machine, so it may be a case that the domain you're accessing the site through does not match on the certificate. This would appear to be a server configuration problem, not a JS/jQuery one, as such we cannot really help you.

Comment: No I don't need to pay for it, it just need a free registration and and be 
validated by the provider. Could this be fixed by running a local NodeJS server and host the website on it, or does it really need a open domain?